# Changing view from custom class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom class. It loads when the app starts. I have to change the view inside this class method.

**Class:**

```
import Foundation

class ChatManager {
    class var sharedInstance: ChatManager {
        struct Singleton { static let instance = ChatManager() }
        return Singleton.instance
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    function changeView() {
       //I need to change view here.
    }
}
```

I can change the view inside a view controller but this class is not an `UIViewController`

What should I do ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change? Why don't you pass it in as input parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to do it in `UIViewController`. Your class should not be responsible for the View part.

But that's not your question. What you could do is send `YourView` as a parameter to the function do some logic there and return it. If you have to resize `YourView` on several different location, then create method for that inside `YourView` class. If you use same logic for several different `UIView`s create `BaseView` and implement that method there, and then inherit in your views `BaseView`.

I have to mention it again, this is not the place to do any UI-related stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you pass your UIView through. I agree with Nick however, you should be doing View logic in a custom View class or the UIViewController class.

```
function changeView(yourView: UIView) {
   //I need to change view here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick. The answer is, don't. You should treat a view controller's views as private. Mucking around with a view controller's views violates the OOP principle of encapsulation.

If you insist on having an outside class make changes to your views, create an instance method in your class that takes a view as a parameter and then applies changes to that view. Then you can call the method from your view controller class to make changes to your view.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that requires a navigation controller. If you are unfamiliar with navigation controllers, I strongly recommend looking at a tutorial. They make life much easier for iOS developers.  Sorry if that code is running off your screen.

```
// Switches to MyViewController, a class I have implemented somewhere else 
func moveToMyView() {

    if let navController = getNavigationController() {

        // The Identifier was set in the Identity Inspector tab on the storyboard (The field is called "Storyboard ID")
        if let myController = navController.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier( "myClassID" ) as? MyViewController {

            // Switch to the newController 
            navController.pushViewController( exerciseController, animated: true )
        }
    }    
}              

// Returns the navigation controller if it exists
func getNavigationController() -> UINavigationController? {

    if let navigationController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController  {

        return navigationController as? UINavigationController
    }
    return nil
}
```